# Create bootable Snow Leopard USB drive/stick from Ubuntu

Tags: macbook-pro, leopard, unix

I need to create an USB drive/stick booting Snow Leopard on an Ubuntu system. Any pointers on how to accomplish this are appreciated.

Comment: I tried to edit your answer a bit because it wasn't too obvious what you are looking for here. If I misread your intentions or want to add additional details, please edit your question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the install DVD or an .ISO rip, you can use the `dd` command to write it to your USB drive.

```
sudo dd if=~/osx-snowleopard.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Just replace `~/osx-snowleopard.iso` with the path and name of the ISO file and `/dev/sdb` with the device node name of your USB stick.

Use the `lsblk` command to figure out which device name is your USB stick.  It's probably going to be `sdb` or `sdc`.  If your geek stick automounts when you plug it into Ubuntu, make sure you unmount it first; just right click the USB stick's partition and click "Eject".

Comment: I have first to format the usb drive in fat32 partition?

Comment: No, you don't have to.  When it writes the ISO image, it'll format the drive with the ISO 9660 file system (which is what CDs and DVDs use).  This way, the USB will be bootable on a Mac.  Just plug in the drive, use lsblk to figure out which one it is (probably /dev/sdb), then run "umount /dev/sdb", then the dd command above.

Comment: Also, dd will take a long time and it doesn't display any sort of progress bar.  Just let it run.  When it gives you back control of the terminal, then you'll know it is finished.